# Login automatically in grails in bootstrap with spring security core

Tags: grails, spring-security

During development i find my self often having to restart my application which in turn results in an extra step of login in manually.

I thought i could add the method call springSercurityService.reauthenticate('myuser') in the bootstrap however i am not sucessfull

Doing the same thing in a controller after the application is started works fine so its is just in the bootstrap that it does not work.
I debugged the code without seeing any obvious errors.

Comment: Ted Naleid's answer is probably your best bet. The authentication is stored in the session, and there's no session or request active in BootStrap, so forcing an authentication there makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit the same issue and how I solved it was to use a bookmarklet (or a custom browser "search engine") that makes it really easy to log back in.  With deep linking enabled, it makes it very easy to continue working on the same page.  After rebooting the server, just refresh the page and it will redirect you to the login page.  Just activate the bookmarklet (or "search engine") and it'll log you in and redirect you back to the page you were working on.

I have a detailed [blog post](http://naleid.com/blog/2011/11/29/speed-up-your-grails-spring-security-development-with-autologin-bookmarklet/) that shows how to get this set up.

Comment: Thanks for this Ted
I ended up creating a simple controller that will call springsecurityService.reauthenticate(), made sure to check if the environment was dev
Had to do it this way since i have a custom authentication provider with that requires a hardware key for the login process
However your solution is nice and general enough to be preferred in most cases

Comment: hi Iman, could you please share your controller code or elaborate it in detail? I also want to do the same but got stucked.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just to avoid having to log in on development mode you can set up the interceptUrlMap property. That property would allow you to set up development mode in a way that wouldn't ask you to login.

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType

grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap

environments {
    development {
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
            '/**':              ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
        ]
    }

}
```

Comment: I would actually need to perform a login so i can get hold of user information. Otherwise my app would not work properly. So everything would need to work as if i made a manual login

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add a servlet filter that will log in the default user if the environment is development.